# How to convert oracle to JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

We are facing issue related to convert Oracle Query to JOOQ Object .

Oracle Query here:

```
select v0 AddressLine1, v1 AddressLine2, v2 AddrCity, v3 AddrProvince, v4 AddrPostal, v5 NameFirst, v6 NameMiddle,
  v7 AddrStreet, v8 NameLast, v9 Phone1, v10 PeopleCode, v11 LicenceNumber, v12 FamilyRSN, v13 PeopleRSN, v14 EmailAddress,
  v15 AddrHouse, v16 StatusCode, v17 ParentRSN, v18 StatusType, v19 FullName 
  from (select x.v0, x.v1, x.v2, x.v3, x.v4, x.v5, x.v6, x.v7, x.v8, x.v9, x.v10, x.v11, x.v12, x.v13, x.v14, x.v15, x.v16, 
  x.v17, x.v18, x.v19, rownum rn from (select amanda7.People.AddressLine1 v0, amanda7.People.AddressLine2 v1, 
  amanda7.People.AddrCity v2, amanda7.People.AddrProvince v3, amanda7.People.AddrPostal v4, amanda7.People.NameFirst v5, 
  amanda7.People.NameMiddle v6, amanda7.People.AddrStreet v7, amanda7.People.NameLast v8, amanda7.People.Phone1 v9, 
  amanda7.People.PeopleCode v10, amanda7.People.LicenceNumber v11, amanda7.People.FamilyRSN v12, amanda7.People.PeopleRSN v13,
  amanda7.People.EmailAddress v14, amanda7.People.AddrHouse v15, amanda7.People.StatusCode v16, amanda7.People.ParentRSN v17,
  amanda7.People.StatusType v18, (nvl(amanda7.People.OrganizationName, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameTitle, '') 
  || nvl(amanda7.People.NameFirst, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameMiddle, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameLast, '') ||
  nvl(amanda7.People.NameSuffix, '')) v19 from amanda7.People order by v19 desc) x where rownum <= (0 + 200))  where rn > 0;
```

JOOQ here:

```
private SelectQuery<Record> getPeopleListQuery(Collection<SQLCondition<?>> conditions) {

        List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDRESS_LINE_1);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDRESS_LINE_2);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDR_CITY);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDR_PROVINCE);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDR_POSTAL);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.NAME_FIRST);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.NAME_MIDDLE);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDR_STREET);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.NAME_LAST);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.PHONE_1);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.PEOPLE_CODE);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.LICENCE_NUMBER);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.FAMILY_RSN);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.PEOPLE_RSN);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.ADDR_HOUSE);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.STATUS_CODE);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.PARENT_RSN);
        fields.add(People.PEOPLE.STATUS_TYPE);
        // Added to provide sort functionality on peopleName on header sort.
        fields.add(DSL.concat(DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.ORGANIZATION_NAME, ""), DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.NAME_TITLE, ""),
                DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.NAME_FIRST, ""), DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.NAME_MIDDLE, ""), DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.NAME_LAST, ""),
                DSL.isnull(People.PEOPLE.NAME_SUFFIX, "")).as("FullName"));
        advanceSearchSelectQuery.addFields(fields);
        advanceSearchSelectQuery.addOrderBy(SortDialogViewModelNew.createJSONString(userSortingChoice));
        return advanceSearchSelectQuery.getSelectQuery();
    }
```

This JOOQ query giving  Exception Invalid column name because of we  are using order by clause  using alias as `FullName` .This query is working fine for SQL but in Oracle DB its giving exception.In Oracle DB the query generated  below the order by clause give v19 instead of `FullName` :

```
 select v0 AddressLine1, v1 AddressLine2, v2 AddrCity, v3 AddrProvince, v4 AddrPostal, v5 NameFirst, v6 NameMiddle,
  v7 AddrStreet, v8 NameLast, v9 Phone1, v10 PeopleCode, v11 LicenceNumber, v12 FamilyRSN, v13 PeopleRSN, v14 EmailAddress,
  v15 AddrHouse, v16 StatusCode, v17 ParentRSN, v18 StatusType, v19 FullName 
  from (select x.v0, x.v1, x.v2, x.v3, x.v4, x.v5, x.v6, x.v7, x.v8, x.v9, x.v10, x.v11, x.v12, x.v13, x.v14, x.v15, x.v16, 
  x.v17, x.v18, x.v19, rownum rn from (select amanda7.People.AddressLine1 v0, amanda7.People.AddressLine2 v1, 
  amanda7.People.AddrCity v2, amanda7.People.AddrProvince v3, amanda7.People.AddrPostal v4, amanda7.People.NameFirst v5, 
  amanda7.People.NameMiddle v6, amanda7.People.AddrStreet v7, amanda7.People.NameLast v8, amanda7.People.Phone1 v9, 
  amanda7.People.PeopleCode v10, amanda7.People.LicenceNumber v11, amanda7.People.FamilyRSN v12, amanda7.People.PeopleRSN v13,
  amanda7.People.EmailAddress v14, amanda7.People.AddrHouse v15, amanda7.People.StatusCode v16, amanda7.People.ParentRSN v17,
  amanda7.People.StatusType v18, (nvl(amanda7.People.OrganizationName, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameTitle, '') 
  || nvl(amanda7.People.NameFirst, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameMiddle, '') || nvl(amanda7.People.NameLast, '') ||
  nvl(amanda7.People.NameSuffix, '')) v19 from amanda7.People order by FullName desc) x where rownum <= (0 + 200))  where rn > 0;
```

Anyone can help me please how to resolved this issue.

Thanks
Sitansu

Comment: I think you ran into this issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2080. What jOOQ version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are encountering had been fixed in jOOQ 3.5.0: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2080

It was a substantial change with risk of regression, which is why the fix wasn't backported to jOOQ 3.4.x versions. If you upgrade your jOOQ version, your query should run just fine.

Comment: Is there any alternate approach to implement this ? We need to show a field which is combination of multiple columns and also need to apply sorting on that field. In sqlserver the above approach is working fine but fails in oracle.

Comment: @Sitansu: An easy workaround would be to order by column index, rather than by column name. Does that help?